# Passing a parameter to JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to build a simple image viewer with JavaFx which would work similar to this:

```
Viewer viewer = new Viewer("path/to/file.jpg");
```

I've tried something along the lines of the code below, but it does not work.

```
public class Viewer extends Application {

private String filePath;

public Viewer(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}

@Override 
public void start(Stage stage) {
    // load the image
    Image image = new Image("file:" + this.filePath);

    // simple displays ImageView the image as is
    ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
    iv1.setImage(image);

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    HBox box = new HBox();
    box.getChildren().add(iv1);
    root.getChildren().add(box);

    stage.setTitle(this.filePath);
    stage.setWidth(415);
    stage.setHeight(200);
    stage.setScene(scene); 
    stage.sizeToScene(); 
    stage.show(); 
}
}
```

Is there a standard way of passing parameters to a JavaFx application?

Comment: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--) should answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you have pass one or more parameters for your SubClass of Application. The Class Abstract Application have a method called launch that receive a String[] args. Then you can pass a parameter for this, eg. `String[]{"--nameOfParameters=value of patameters",...}` . You get the paramaters for `getParameters().getNamed().get("name of parameters")`.

A below I put a example.

```
public class Viewer extends Application {

        @Override 
        public void start(Stage stage) {
          // load the image
          Image image = new Image("file:" + getParameters().getNamed().get("file"));
          ...
        }

        public void caller(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        /**
         * This is a example of the passing a parameters 
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             (new Viewer()).caller(new String[]{"--file=path/to/file.jpg"});
        }

    }
```

Comment: In Java 8 (and in many deployment styles in earlier versions), the main(...) method is not invoked at all, so this approach won't work.

Comment: @James_D Yes I agree with you. I'm only example for testing. In fact, you use this in your program (new Viewer()).caller(new String[]{"--file=path/to/file.jpg"}); or  (new Viewer()).launch(new String[]{"--file=path/to/file.jpg"});

Answer (score 1):

You could simply pass an unnamed parameter

```
Parameters parameters = getParameters();
List<String> unnamedParameters = parameters.getUnnamed();
filePath = unnamedParameters.get(0); // assumes path/to/file.jpg has been passed
```